# Clicking on "New -> Image asset" in android studio is not opening the image asset dialogue

Tags: android, android-studio

Clicking on "New -> Image asset" in android studio is not opening the image asset dialogue. I'm not getting any errors either. It's not hanging. It just appears that this one feature is not working in android studio. Has anyone else faced the same issue?

Comment: Works fine here, maybe try invalidating caches. Or reinstall AS

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered how to do it.

In Android Studio, do File --> Open

Then choose your project's Android folder, and select to open it in a new window.

Wait something like 45 seconds for all the data to come in, and then after that right click on the 'res' folder, and you shall then see the option to open the image asset studio.